# How to make a run configuration in maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, configuration, pom.xml

Every time i make a git clone i must set up the run configuration. Open "edit run configuration" in Intellij Idea. Choose maven - console - tomcat7:run, name - Run. How to put it into a pom.xml to get rid of this repeating steps every time. Thanks

Comment: I am not an IntelliJack, but your run configuration seems to be an IntelliJ concept, so it is probably saved in some project configuration files of IntelliJ. It cannot be put into the POM.

Comment: what settings do you repeat? those can probably just be added into the configuration section of the plugin: https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html - plan B would be to tick the intellij checkbox "share configuration" and commit that run configuration into VCS as well